# Can Knockout.js change variable which is not in the viewModel

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

This is my sample code
    HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: a"/>
```

And in JavaScript I want something like.

```
var a = 5; 
a = ko.observable(a);
```

But i want to keep a number. And when i change a the input to change and when I change the input a to change.

Comment: The important question is: how do you plan on changing the value of `a` if not through the `input`? Once you answer this question we can help you. In your JS you can change the value of `a` by simply writing: `a(newvalue)` as opposed to the standard `a = newvalue`.

Comment: Yes I would like to change the variable the both ways trough the input and trough the JS. And I would like to keep it number not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewModel->Scope` is possible, but `Scope->ViewModel` is *not* possible:

```
 var nonObservable = 5,
     observable = ko.observable(nonObservable);

// ViewModel->Scope
observable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    nonObservable = newValue;
});

// Scope->ViewModel
observable("new value");

// This however, will not work
nonObservable = "not in any way connected";
```

The reason for this is that there is no way for knockout to detect what name you are binding it to (`ko.observable` just knows that it has been given the value `5`, not that it has been given the name `nonObservable`) ... and even if it *could* detect this, you would probably not want to do this by default.